# How can I uninstall the Child of Light demo?

Tags: ubisoft-connect, child-of-light

I've played through the Child of Light demo (installed from Steam but launched from Uplay), then some time afterwards purchased and downloaded the full version (again, bought and downloaded from Steam, then launched from Uplay).

However, I did not uninstall the demo before installing the full version of the game, and now there's both the demo and the full version of the game in Uplay's games list. When I try to use the 'Uninstall' option from the game's menu, all it does is open up the Programs and Features control panel, where the demo is nowhere to be found.

[image]

Now I'm rather confused. Is the demo overwritten/uninstalled automatically when the full version is installed, and Uplay just didn't notice, or is the demo somewhere out there, but the uninstall option isn't available? And if it is the latter, how can I uninstall the demo to free up the disk space?

Comment: @PriatePansy, it seems like it. (The demo has been overridden)

Comment: Also, have you checked the installation folders for the demo data?

Answer (score 2):

Since uPlay and many other distribution programs store game metadata (ie. installation, whether first-time checks have been run, install status, CD keys, etc.) separately to the game files.

Since you installed the full version through Steam, all it does it puts new metadata (invidiual games' metadata are saved as individual files) and the game files (which goes into the same location as the demo), then launch through uPlay.

If you would've installed through uPlay, it would've removed the demo's metadata (making it not appear) and then overridden/deleted the demo.

---

The only thing I can suggest is that finding the relevant metadata for the demo and manually removing any leftover files in the installation folders.